# using outer query variable in inner query in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I have a SPARQL query that has the structure:

```
{

  ?name1 :hasAddress ?address1
  ?name2 :hasAddress ?address2

  {

    select COUNT(DISTINCT ?city1) as ?DistinctCities
    {
      ?city1 :isIn ?address1
      ?city2 :isIn ?address2
      ?city1 :isConnectedTo ?city2
    }

  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not look like `?address1` (and `?address2`) in the outer query is being used in the inner query. I found this out because when I run the inner query by itself for literal values of `?address1` and `?address2`, it gives me different values from the compound query.

Comment: Inner queries are always executed first, not the other way around. If you need something also in the inner query, put the triple patterns there as well. If you need information from the inner query in the outer query, propagate it in the `SELECT` part (don't forget that once you use aggregate functions like `COUNT`, grouping will be necessary.

Comment: @AKSW please move your comment to an answer

Comment: Also note that your inner query isn't syntactically valid.  You need parenthesis around the `COUNT(...) as ...`. You can check at http://sparql.org/validate/query.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'd accept an answer if someone posts one.